# RoR , trouble with full_title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am on Chapter 4 of Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial, and having some troubles with rspec and using the full_title helper function. In part 4.1 of the tutorial, I have the helper code as follows.

app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
  end
end
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                           "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  let(:base_title) {"Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"}

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end

    it "should have the base title" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App")
    end

    it "should not have a custom page title" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).not_to have_title('| Home')
    end
  end

end
```

app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb

```
<h1>Sample App</h1>
    <p>this is the home page for the <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    sample application.</p>
```

And when I try to run test I get this:

```
gvyntyk@gvyntyk-r60:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
FFF

Failures:

  1) Static pages Home page should not have a custom page title
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `base_title' for #<#<Class:0xb0ea7f8>:0xb0ea1cc>
     # ./app/helpers/application_helper.rb:6:in `full_title'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___36363065_93308240'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Static pages Home page should have the base title
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `base_title' for #<#<Class:0xb0ea7f8>:0x961e58c>
     # ./app/helpers/application_helper.rb:6:in `full_title'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___36363065_93308240'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `base_title' for #<#<Class:0xb0ea7f8>:0x9c13244>
     # ./app/helpers/application_helper.rb:6:in `full_title'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___36363065_93308240'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.23 seconds
3 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19 # Static pages Home page should not have a custom page title
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:14 # Static pages Home page should have the base title
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:9 # Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
```

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong here?

Comment: Try moving the `let` to be after the second describe not the first.

Comment: I've moved let, but I get the same error. Even when I commented this line I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you've not posted the exact code for what the tests are running against. I'm not seeing how by what you've posted the code is even getting to full_title in the helper as you only have yeild(:title) in application.html.erb. Nothing is calling full_title.

Looking at Michaels example in the book you need to have full_title(yield(:title)) in the title tags removing what you've got posted there.

Comment: I was inattentive, I edited my cod andnow it works correctly. Thanks.